# Clean in a makefile do not work

Tags: kernel-module

I have created a Makefile for building the "hello world" kernel module and I am able to compile and get a `.ko` object and insert that module.

But the clean function in the Makefile does not removing the `.ko` extension files from the directory when the kernel module is removed.

PFB the makefile lines I have used.

```
obj-m +=hello.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Please correct me if I have done wrong inside the make file.

Comment: Makefile looks correct. Check, that you use tab-intended receipt for `clean` target. Does `make clean` removes `.o` files and other ones, but not `.ko` file? What output of `make clean` command?

Comment: Hi, make clean doesn't removing the .o files also so I have replaced the "make -c" line with  rm *.o but still it is not removing any files.

Comment: Try to run receipt for `clean` target in the command line. If it works, your problem is in incorrectly written recept in the makefile. Otherwise, something wrong with your kernel build.

Comment: I have tried to run the same command in command line make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean but it throws error.make: invalid option -- '/'
make: invalid option -- 'u'
Usage: make [options] [target] ...
Options:
So could you please let me know how to run the clean through command line.

Comment: For run directly in the command line, command should be: `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean`. You can also try hardcoded paths: instead of `$(uname -r)` and `$(pwd)` use output of these commands (`uname -r` and `pwd`).

Comment: When I run this command I got this error.                                        make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-60-generic-pae/build /root/linuxdevice clean
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-60-generic-pae'
make: Nothing to be done for `/root/linuxdevice'.
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-60-generic-pae/ubuntu/aufs/Makefile:2: ubuntu/aufs/magic.mk: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `ubuntu/aufs/magic.mk'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [ubuntu/aufs] Error 2
make: *** [_clean_ubuntu] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-60-generic-pae'

Comment: You forget to type `M=` before `/root/linuxdevice`.

Comment: Yes the clean command is working fine through command line.So what could be the reason it is not working inside a make file

Comment: Try to use hardcoded paths in the makefile. If it works, change these paths to calculated one-by-one, as catch the moment when it breaks. This is an usual way for debug.

Comment: Take command, which works for you in the command line, and use it as a receipt for `clean` target in the makefile.

Comment: I have modified the clean in make file with this command                        rm !(hello.c|Makefile). It works in command line but not through makefile.    can we debug  a make file using gdb or any other debugging tools

Comment: Special characters(like `!`) are intepreted by make first, so they should be appropriately escaped to be passed to the shell. Try command without special characters.

Comment: Yes now it works it was just a syntax mistake